# Pointers are used to store address, but in strings like char *ptr = "abc" then if you print 'ptr' why it is printed abc instead of address

Tags: c, string, memory-management, embedded

Pointers are used for mainly to store the address of other variable like below code,

```
char a='A',*p;
p=&a;
printf("p: %p *p: %c p: %c\n",p,*p,p);

output: p: 0x7ffc81b8d9ef *p: A p: �
```

1.From above output if we want to print 'p' value then it's getting garbage value.

*In strings*

```
char *p ="A";
printf("p: %p *p: %c p: %s\n",p,*p,p);

output:p: 0x55ce091de714 *p: A p: A
```

2.From above output if we want to print 'p' value then it's print as A.

From 1 & 2 'p' is used for store the address only but in 2nd case why it is printing total string and
why it is unable to print value in 1st case.

How can we ensure this ?

Comment: because `"A"` is the array `char[2]{'A', 0}` and `p` points to the first element of the array.

Comment: In the first example the third argument `p` is a pointer, which is incompatible with `%c` format. In the second example `%s` *does* expect a pointer.

Comment: because `%c` is expecting `char`, while `%s` is expecting `char*`.

Comment: but pointer is used to store address only but why it is printing string.

Comment: Because in the second example `%s` expects a pointer. Which is what it gets.

Comment: Because `printf` is implemented in such a way, that when it sees `%s`, it will take that address and will print the string starting at that address.

Comment: In C, a string is an array of characters ending with a null byte. Arrays are converted to a pointers when passed as function parameters, so `%s` expects the argument to be a pointer.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I tried with format specifier %s in example 1 but i am getting segmentation fault.

Comment: That's because `char a` is not a string.

Comment: In the first example you pass `*p` for `%c` and it works, you also pass `p` for `%c` and it doesn't work. Why do you expect them both to work?

Comment: `p` does not point to a string (or, more precisely, to the initial element of a string) in example 1.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I am not bother about that 1st example of *p and p, In 2nd example 'P' is used to store base address of string only then if we want to print 'p' it should print address (or) if you give other format specifier then it should give junk value.

Comment: I suggest you change the string in the example to the `"ABC"` of which you speak. You''ll then get different results from `%c` (`A`) and `%s` (`ABC`).

Comment: Pointers don't store strings. The string has its own storage in memory somewhere, and the pointer tells you where that storage is

Comment: The question in your title appears to bear little relationship to the body text.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.From above output if we want to print 'p' value then it's getting garbage value.

The `%c` conversion specifier expects its argument to have type `char`.  `p` has type `char *` and stores the address of `a`.  Because of this type mismatch, the behavior is *undefined* and the output could quite literally be anything.  One possibility is that `printf` is trying to interpret the first byte of `p` as a `char`, but the value is likely outside the range of printable characters in the basic character set, so you get a glyph in whatever extended character set is used by the system.

> 2.From above output if we want to print 'p' value then it's print as A.

The `%s` conversion specifier expects its argument to have type `char *` and to point to the first character in a *string*.  It then prints each successive character of that string until it sees the string terminator.  If your string was `"ABC"`, then the output would be `p: <some address> *p: A p: ABC`.